# Simplify nested for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So I'm working on a pdf upload system where general info about the pdf file is one array and each of these general infos has an array of specific pdf files. I'm using some of the values of the general info inside of the specific pdf files so I came up with a nested for loop solution

```
const allPdfFiles: any[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < pdfInfos.length; i += 1) {
  const allPdfFilesExtended: PDFinfoExtended[] = pdfInfos[i].pages as PDFinfoExtended[];

  allPdfFilesExtended.forEach(pdfFile => {
    pdfFile['orgFileName'] = pdfInfos[i].orgFileName;
    pdfFile['planTitleExists'] = false;
    pdfFile['deviceId'] = pdfInfos[i].deviceId;
    pdfFile['userId'] = pdfInfos[i].userId;
    pdfFile['projectId'] = pdfInfos[i].projectId;
    pdfFile['id'] = pdfInfos[i].id;
  });

  allPdfFiles.push(...allPdfFilesExtended);
}
```

Unfortunately this cause some bottleneck for the pdf file search I need to simplify it to at least O(n). Would be glad for suggestions. Thank you

Comment: But you have nested datastructure. A solution that's computed will always be `O(n^2)` since you always need to go over all parent elements *and* all child elements. Not sure how you expect that to be done in `O(n)`

Comment: I guess if all PDF files are static and never (or rarely) change, you can just maintain a lookup index for them. Not sure if that would be helpful, though.

Comment: I was hoping that someone would see something that I'm missing even though it is pretty simple nested for loop but yeah ...

Comment: Are you simply copying metadata from `pdfInfos[i]` onto the individual sub-objects (`pdfFile`)? Did I understand that correctly? A solution might be anything that prevents you from having to do this. If you can get from the `pdfFile` to the metadata object directly (eg. by index or a reference) then having the data on the `pdfFile` itself might be redundant.

Comment: this is not javascript. and there is no trace of reactjs either.

Comment: @grodzi removed the tag

Comment: As Ben said, why even copy that meta data? Is there any specific reason not to work with `pdfInfos` alone/directly?

Comment: The reason is that after this nested for loop I'm looping through `allPdfFiles` and rendering individual pdfFiles `this.pdfFileRender(this.state.allPdfFiles[i]` - inside this function I need the metadata from `pdfInfos`;

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Why not pass the appropriate `pdfInfos` entry as a second parameter?` Like (*simplified*): `pdfInfos.forEach(pdfInfo => {
  pdfInfo.pages.forEach(page => {
    pdfFileRender(page, pdfInfo)
  });
});`

Comment: @Yoshi correct me if I'm wrong but isn't it still complexity of O(n^2) ?

Comment: I don't think so, if I understood your code correctly, it should be O(n), with n being the total number of `pdfInfos[x].pages`. Or maybe O(n+m), where m is the total number of `pdfInfos`, when some of them have no pages.

Comment: That being said, I don't even think your original code is O(n^2). You're basically doing the same thing, one pass over `pdfInfos` and for each, one pass over all it's pages. That's not n^2, rather roughly the number of total pages.

Comment: if there are 100 pdf files (pdfInfos) and each as 100 pages than the complexity should be 100^2 and i think the same goes for the nested foreach loop example

Comment: you should insist/develop on __why__ you want to copy the metadata onto each pdfExtended. You say for "search" but this is a bit evasive. The solution may come not to find a technical trick to put your metadata onto all the pdfextended, but rather propose a lazy way to access the meta data. Anyway if you search through all your files, that'd still be O(n^2)